# How do I stop Apache from running as root?

Tags: permissions, users, root, apache-httpd

New on the job, small place, and the security stuff just landed on my desk. I was hired to be a front-end developer. Happy to learn new things, but never had to do sysadmin stuff before.

I started digging and it appears that apache, the site, and everything is running on root. There are no other groups or users. ACK!

What steps should I take to change this? I know that this is a big no-no...

Bonus points if anyone can please point me to a good basic 101 tutorial on apache/php security.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is unusual to find Apache running as `root` in any stock configuration.  How have you determined that Apache is running as root?  Note that Apache must *start up* as root in order to bind to privileged ports, but typically sheds its privileges later on.

You can look in your Apache configuration (often in `/etc/httpd` or `/etc/apache2`, depending on your distribution) for the `User` and `Group` directives (documented [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#user)).  These two directives control under what user id Apache runs.

It is also unusual to find a system that has "no other groups or users".  What do `getent passwd` and `getent group` show?  Are there *really* no other users or groups other than `root`?  Most distributions ship with an `apache` or `www-data` user or somesuch and a matching configuration that will run Apache as that user.

There are a variety of introductory guides out there to Apache configuration and security.  A simple Google search yields many likely looking results.  The RedHat/CentOS [Deployment Guide](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/ch-httpd.html) is a good place to start (if you're on a RedHat/CentOS system).

Comment: Thanks, yeah, it wasn't running off root, but it seems that everything else has been done using root. all the folders, files, etc. I'll need to work out how to change that.

Comment: Well...not necessarily.  You don't want the files owned by the same user as the running Apache process.  Ideally, a compromise in the web server will not result in an attacker being able to modify your Apache configuration or web content.

Answer (score 0):

You can run Apache as any user with port numbers greater than the privileged port number 1024+. Then use port forwarding to forward traffic from ports 80 and 443 to your specific ports.